# trigger event before content is parsed after ajax

Tags: 7, ajax

I want to ajaxify my site. Everything, that is usally parsed as "Page Content" sould be opened in a lightbox. 
So the idea is to ajaxify every link and let #lightbox be filled with the result.

but before ajax parses the request-result, I want some javascript to be done. So I want an event to be triggered after the ajax respond, and want to parse the result by myself.

any suggestions?

<s>**EDIT:**</s>

I could store the content in an hidden div#object, and use an `ajax_command_invoke('body','trigger',array('myevent'))`  to trigger a function attached to `myevent`. Does this make sense?
than I just dont know how to implement this to all links.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using AJAX API? All the [Ajax commands](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21ajax.inc/group/ajax_commands/7) have the same return, for example

```
array(
    'command' => 'insert',
    'method' => 'html',
    'selector' => $selector,
    'data' => $html,
    'settings' => $settings,
);
```

And if you open the file misc/ajax.js, you will find insert() function in Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands. I think now you got the idea right? You just need to define a new ajax command by extending standard library, for example

```
Drupal.ajax.prototype.commands.lightbox = function (ajax, response, status) {
    // Do something with response.
};
```

And on server side, you just need to return

```
array(
    'command' => 'lightbox',
);
```

You can put more options in the command like what core does.

Comment: thx, this sounds good! I'll try

Comment: maybe you have any suggestions on my other question:
http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/129802/ajaxify-content-via-a-callback-function?lq=1